# AngularJS validation using ng-messages without a form control

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation, ng-messages

I store time as an integer of minutes in the database/model. However, I want to display it to the user in decimal hours (and let them edit the value using a number of buttons).

At the moment I have this:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="{{vm.time.minutes|hoursMinutes}}" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <ix-time-picker minutes="vm.time.minutes"></ix-time-picker>
    </span>
</p>
```

Of the 2 elements in the `p` tag:

1. The `input type="text"` works fine as the display mechanism. The `hoursMinutes` filter returns a formatted value, e.g. for 90 mins it will return '1 hour 30 mins'.
2. The `ix-time-picker` directive pops up a modal window with buttons such as `15 mins`, `30 mins`, `45 mins`, `1 hour`, `1:15 hours`, etc.

This works fine - except for validation. I'm using `ng-messages` and I can't work out how to display the validation for the `required` state:

```
<li class="help-block has-error"
    ng-if="mainForm.$submitted"
    ng-messages="mainForm.minutes.$error">
    <span ng-message="required">
        Minutes is required.
    </span>
</li>
```

I don't have a control on the form called `minutes` (at least with an `ng-model`) so it won't display the message. I could add a hidden `input` with `ng-model="vm.times.minutes"` but as I need to use this repeatedly through the application, I'd prefer not to do that. Or at least I'd like to build some kind of common directive that merges the ability to have an `ng-model` on a control with the ability to display a `value` that is different to the model value, if that's possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Aha - one option is to make the `input` a `label`:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <label id="minutes" name="minutes" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">{{vm.time.minutes|hoursMinutes}}</label>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <ix-time-picker minutes="vm.time.minutes"></ix-time-picker>
    </span>
</p>
```

Then it displays correctly and it validates.